# How use mousedown/click events for disabled objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Considering the following, how can I enable a disabled element on click?

```
$("element").click(function(){
    //enable element
});
```

Comment: Is the element that is being "enabled" the same as the one being clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: @patrick - yes, the element being click is the one that needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with is:

```
$('label').click(
    function(){
        $(this).next(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Since the disabled element itself doesn't, at least in Chrome 8/Ubuntu 10.10, respond to click events.

This does assume, of course, that the `label` precedes the disabled element, and doesnt', in its current form, check that the label corresponds to the next disabled element.

[JS Fiddle demo of the above](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wSnJP/).

---

**Edited** to revise the approach, so clicking on the `label` affects only the relevant `input`:

```
$('label').click(
    function(){
        var relevantInput = $(this).attr('for');
        $('#' + relevantInput)
            .removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wSnJP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Dupilicate: [Jquery event on a disabled input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input)