# Select the text in the input field, but the editing is disabled

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have a simple txt input field:

`<input type="text" name="" value="http://google.com" />`

If i click inside the input, i want to select the text. This part is fine with this:

> $('input.highlight').click(function(){
>
> $(this).focus().select();
>
> return false;
>
> });

But, i want to disable the editing also. If i put a return false; to the keydown event, the ctrl+c is not working. If i put disabled="disabled" to the input, the select is not working.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to add the **readonly** attribute instead of *disabled*:

```
<input type="text" name="" readonly="readonly" value="http://google.com" />
```

Comment: Which exact version of Chrome? This is very basic HTML (quite possibly since the HTML Input element was created) - if this fails in a nightly this might be a regression bug.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use the `keypress()` and  `preventDefault()` functions

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
    $(this).focus().select();
    $(this).keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    })

});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/hAVg9/

Answer (score 0):

Readonly purpose is very different than disabled, and also theirs layout is very different.

To select or even copy text from an disabled input text, one can follow 
[Andy E suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/3199081)

Or, as my case, to have a button (input-group-appended) associated to the input text. 
And then on button click:

1. enable input text
2. select or focus or what ever you want to do
3. disable again

Like this:

```
$('#btnCopy').click(function(){
    $('#txtInputDisabled').removeAttr('disabled');  
    $('#txtInputDisabled').select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $('#txtInputDisabled').attr('disabled','disabled');  
});
```

Complete example no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DnlCYan/xpvt214o/862699/)