# HTML ondblclick on disabled Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dom-events, double-click

How can I enable the double click event for a disabled checkbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately onclick and ondblclick does not work on disabled inputs.