# Add click event on disabled textarea (jquery + ui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input)

I am making an edit dialog for a device. The device has a comment-field in the database. This comment-field only has to be editable when the textarea representing it is not disabled.

I know by trial and error that

```
$("#textarea").click(function(){
// textarea will be enabled here
});
```

Doesn't work, since the textarea is disabled... is there a way around this or another way to add a click event to a disabled element?

**EDIT:**

James link worked.
[Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input)

One problem though. IE don't support position absolute on divs when are empty. If i fill the div with a color in CSS it displays, but if i don't and just set the top,bottom,left,right and position it wont't show.. anyone know a fix fore this? (im fine with it only working in FF for now)

thanks again

Comment: Welcome to SO! No need to add a comment when you edit, the revision history is sufficient :)

Comment: I god damn love you james... you are the man :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make the text area readonly instead of disabled. it will have the same effect and will be clickable.

```
<textarea readonly=true>
    aaa
</textarea>

$("textarea").click(function(){
alert(123);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfect for my system. Forgot all about that textarea has a readonly attribute.