# jQuery hover having no effect on a readonly input element

Tags: jquery

I have an input element with `readonly` set to true (`"readonly"`). However, when I try to apply a hover effect in jQuery, no results are seen.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/zkJXY/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: Can you try to maybe make a jsfiddle so we can see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your selector

change `$('.input')` into `$('input')` and it works

Comment: the selector is wrong in the fiddle ... thats right but its not solving the problem

Comment: alright dont forget to use jquery instead of mootools in jsfiddle *$#!0?* :D

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be `$(':input')`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zkJXY/4/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe removing readonly on mouseenter,
adding it again on mouseleave.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8X86r/2/