# Call function for disabled elements

Tags: javascript, element

I have a function that works perfectly if you want to expand an `input type=text` with more than 20 characters. My problem is, how to apply this function for disabled inputs? To better understand the behavior of my function check my example on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/168/

```
$('input[type!="submit"]').focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
        $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
        $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
        $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
    }
}).blur(function(){ 
    var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
    $(this).animate({
        width: w
    }, 'slow');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('cooling');
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel said the `focus` and `blur` event will not work with the `disabled` `input`. Then for this purpose, `hover, mouseenter or mouseover, mouseleave or mouseout` are the events can be used but i could not find it working but i do found `mousemove` for `expanding` it. you can use it it it solve your problem.

```
$('input:disabled').mousemove(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
       $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
       $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
       $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
      }
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/raj_er04/DCjYA/174/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't get to focus an disabled element you should build a workaround for this. Or use another function for this?

EDIT: Probably this could be helpful for you: [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: and how do I integrate this in my function: not really want to use another function :((