# How to cycle an Element from disabled to enabled in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two fields on my webpage. When one of then is focused I want to disable the other one, but if the user then clicks the disabled field, I want it to disable the first fields and then enable the new focused field. Is this possible in javascript?

so far I've tried:

```
<script lang="text/javascript">

        function disableSum(){
            document.getElementById('BugID').disabled=false;
            document.getElementById('Summary').disabled=true;
            console.log('Sum Disabled');
        }

        function disableBug(){
            document.getElementById('BugID').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('Summary').disabled=false;
            console.log('Bug Disabled');
        }

        function checkInput(){

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: You cannot do this - events are not fired on disabled inputs

Comment: is there any way around this... i.e another attribute or some function that I can write?

Comment: Check the answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input <- its using jQuery - but the principal is the same ...

Comment: @Shahab - you could use CSS to style the field such that it looks like it's disabled but then still allow it to be clickable.

Comment: what about using a radio button to control the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following idea might seem a little bit complicated, but you could play with a pair of visible/hidden fields to get this behavior.

See how it behaves here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TQxSh/

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp):

> The disabled property sets or returns whether an element is disabled,
>   or not.
>
> A disabled element is unusable and un-clickable. Disabled elements are
>   usually rendered in gray by default in browsers.

Comment: is there anything similar to the disabled attribute that will allow me to do what I want?

Comment: @ManseUK - wow - there's been some real mess-ups there based on that site.  I will say though that I have found w3schools very helpful in the past many a time when needing to look up css and javascript attributes and use them.

Comment: @ManseUK - sorry, but some of the things that w3fools.com is purporting are not correct - for instance, they say "Professional web developers do not recommend the use of WYSIWYG editors."  There are many web developers that use and highly recommend tools like Dreamweaver for development.  I think a lot of opinions are expressed at that site but they aren't necessarily absolutely true.