# How to add action to the disabled elements via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Purpose:
To make sure some elements couldn't be modified, I disabled some elements once the page was loaded. But if I double clicked the element, the element could be modifiable.

Please see the below code.

My version is jquery-1.5.min.js

```
function disableAccounts($column){
    $column.find('.input_application').attr("disabled","true");
}
```

// this doesn't work since '.input_username' has been disabled.

```
function addEditUsername($column){
    $column.find('.input_username').dblclick(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is tricky.

One way to handle this would be to wrap `.input_username` with some span element. Then, you can check the `dblclick` event on it, check if the `.input_application` is disabled, and enable it if it is.

Sample code:

HTML:

```
<span id="wrapper"><input class="input_username" /></span>
<input class="input_application" disabled="disabled" />
```

Javascript (pseudo code):

```
$('#wrapper').dblclick(function() {
    if ($('.input_application').is('disabled')) {
        // your code here
    }
})
```

But I'd say [gdoron's answer about `readonly`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837030/851498) is better.

Comment: Thank you~ it looks wrap <span> is the best solution for the disabled elements. Readonly is better.

Answer (score 2):

You got two options:
**1. Change from `disabled` to `readonly`:**

```
function disableAccounts($column){
    $column.find('.input_application').attr("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

`disabled` disables events, while `readonly` does not.

**2. Surround the input with a span, and attach dbclick event to the `<sapn>`.**

```
<span id='surrounding'>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class=".input_username" />
</span>​

function addEditUsername($column){
    $column.find('.#surrounding').dblclick(function(){
        $(this).find('.input_username').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}

$column.find('#surrounding').dblclick(function(){...
```

Read this for more info: [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100319/601179)