# javascript enable input on double click

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with some inputs disabled.  I want these inputs to be enabled when double clicked.  Unfortunately, JS events seem not to fire on disabled inputs.

```
<input type="text" value="asdf" disabled="disabled" ondblclick="this.disabled=false;">​
```

Is there a way around this limitation?

Or am I just going to have to wrap any affected input in a span to house the event?

http://jsfiddle.net/vhktx/

Comment: duplicate, you'll find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: Not everyone uses jQuery.  Also, I'm looking for a non-wrap solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ondblclick` does not get fired on a `disabled` element, you should mark it as `readonly`:

```
<input type="text" value="asdf" readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhktx/4/

Comment: Yes, this is a preferred solution.  Thank you.

Comment: You can also add `onblur="this.readOnly='true';"` to make it return to its read-only state when clicked outside the input. And use the `:read-only` CSS tag to style the element while it's read-only vs editable.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to wrap the element in a container since the the event will not fire on disabled elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsYFd/)

```
<div ondblclick="document.getElementById('test').disabled=false;">
    <input type="text" id="test" value="asdf" disabled="disabled"></div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a non-wrap solution.

Comment: There is not a non-wrap solution if you're using the native disabled state of an element.

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox Nightly 16 when dblclicking in the input. Funny how it works even in IE though.

Comment: It's a workable solution, but if I were going to wrap, I would write it leaner as: `<span ondblclick="this.childNodes[0].disabled=false;"><input type="text" value="asdf" disabled="disabled"></span>`

Comment: @Umbrella that's undoubtedly tidier. But still doesn't work on Firefox, to whom that may concern.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that is marked correct does not revert the input back to needing another double-click to edit again.

Add this onchange function to do so:

```
onchange="this.readOnly='true';"
```

The whole thing should be:

```
onchange="this.readOnly='true';" readonly="true" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';"
```

Answer (score -1):

this will do! works for me, As 'disabled' and 'readonly' appears almost the same(at least in bootstrap). inline scripts don't work with the disabled attr.

```
<input type="text" ondblclick="this.readOnly=false;" readonly/>
```