# Can't get .click() to work on a disabled textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm using jQuery. I have a disabled textarea: `<textarea id="textarea" disabled="disabled"></textarea>`. I want to make it so that when a user clicks on the textarea, it will do something, such as an alert box. So, I have `$('#textarea').click(function() { alert('Test'); });`.

However, this only works when the textarea is not disabled. So, how can I make the click event fire even when the textarea is disabled?

Comment: you may set text to "" on key up instead of disabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of disabling it, you could either try simulating the disabled behaviour with CSS and continue receiving mouse events from it.

Or see this answer [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input)
where `Andy E` shows how you can place an invisible element (an overlay) on top of the input for receiving those mouse events when the input is disabled.

He removes the overlay and enables the input when it is clicked, but you could change the behavior to anything you'd like.

Answer (score 12):

instead of `disabled="disabled"` why not use `readonly`, readyonly is alomst same as disabled and the click event will works

Comment: True, and you can even style readonly textarea's to look like its disabled. +1

Answer (score 2):

Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements. However, Firefox doesn't exhibit this behaviour, it just does nothing at all when you click on a disabled element.

You could do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) { 
    if (e.target.id === 'textarea') alert('works');
});​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/13/)

But it's probably not cross-browser!

Another, and possible better way to do it, is to place another element on top of the disabled one and catch events on that element, something like :

```
var t = $("#textarea"),
    over = $('<div</div>');
    over.css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: t.position().top,
        left: t.position().left,
        width: t.outerWidth(),
        height: t.outerHeight(),
        zIndex: 1000,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        opacity: 0
    });

t.after(over);

$(over).on('click', function() { 
    alert('works');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/18/)

Comment: 1+ Very nice and simple solution.

Comment: You will need to specify an explicit value for top and left in the CSS for the textarea for `t.css("left"|"top")` to work as intended. Try `.offset()` or setting left and top to 0px and applying `position: relative` to the container of the textarea.

Comment: @CharlieRudenstål - There are ways around almost anything, just did'nt feel like spending more time on it. Edited my answer, should work in all browsers, and with most styles etc.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't my intent to disparage your answer. Was more of a hint to the OP than anything else. I'm actually about to upvote this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled elements don't fire click events. That's part of them being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You cant fire click event from disabled elements, though you can set the value  e-g:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6tdn/28/