# jquery mouseenter, hover events not firing

Tags: jquery

Currently trying to bind the mouseenter or hover events for a Input tag, my code is somewhat like below

```
$('#details_Owner').hover(HoverIn, HoverOut);
$('#details_Owner').mouseenter(HoverIn);


$(e.srcElement)
    .parent('.column')
    .children("div")
    .each(function(item) { $(this).remove()});


d = $('<div />')
    .addClass("cstooltip")
    .text($(e.srcElement).val())
    .hide()

$(e.srcElement).parent('.column').append(d);
$(e.srcElement)
    .parent('.column')
    .children("div")
    .show()
```

The thing that is causing problems is when the input tag is disabled, the events don't fire, is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relataed topic : [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

In summary :

> Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will
>   propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM
>   tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements.
>   However, Firefox doesn't exhibit this behaviour, it just does nothing
>   at all when you click on a disabled element.

But you will find a workaround if needed on the topic mentionned above

Comment: Thanks, i got the answer from the linked topic.