# HTML & Javascript - how to emulate disabled input (hide caret)?

Tags: javascript, html, emulation, disabled-input

What I need is a disabled input which would fire events.
But since Firefox doesn't support that, I'd like to emulate it somehow.

Which basically means, disallow editing and hide caret. I don't care about appearance.

I've seen this CSS used: `user-select: none;`
But that's not what I want - 1) user can still edit 2) I want it to be selectable.

I don't want the approach of overlaying really disabled input with a  and catching it's events - it's not well portable.

Related: [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: So you want to disallow editing, but it should be editable ...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the user-select paragraph. Reworded.

Comment: Oh I see - you mean, those are the *problems* with just using the `user-select` setting.  I get it now!  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically cancel every keydown event on the input. However this would still show the carret:

```
<input type="text" id="disabled_input" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('disabled_input').keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // or simply return false;
});
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('disabled_input').onkeydown = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // or simply return false;
};
```

Comment: Not sure that the user is using jQuery... he didn't tag it or mention it.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Updated with pure javascript

Comment: Ah, preventDefault(). Will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap it in another element and place the event handler on that element?

For instance

```
<div class="disabledwrapper">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="test" value="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Because Firefox doesn't send click events. They are not fired at all, nowhere in DOM. And I need click event to e.g. navigate to a URL contained in the input.