# Can't Position div on top of radio I.E

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, radio-button, z-index

I have a small app that has disabled options that require an upgrade to enable. When a user clicks to set the option, a div is shown that gives them upgrade instructions. It works great in Firefox and Chrome (yet to test Opera or Safari) but it doesn't work in I.E. (any version).

In the testing I've done, it seems as though the javascript works, but if you click directly on the input element, the script isn't run. If you click just outside of the element (in this case, a radio button) then it works. The div with a class of hidden-input should be displayed over the top, but it seems as though it's displayed around it. Nothing I've done with z-index seems to work, including a fix from http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/ I'm guessing others have experienced this issue, but I'm not sure how it can be fixed. Below is the html and javascript for reference.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="wcmenucart[cart_icon][1]" name="wcmenucart[cart_icon]" value="1" disabled="" />
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;" class="hidden-input-icon">
    </div>
</div>
<span style="display:none;" class="pro-icon"><i> Available in the <a href="#">Pro Version</a></i></span>
```

Javascript - seems to work fine, but just in case...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.hidden-input-icon').click(function() {
        jQuery('.pro-icon').show('slow');
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

Neither **.hidden-input-icon** or **.pro-icon** have css styles. The **.pro-icon** div contains `style="display:none;"` and the **.hidden-input-icon** div contains `style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"`

**Edit:**

There's a fiddle with my code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dfkBb/7/) Hopefully that will help shed some light on the situation.

Comment: can you include your css too?

Comment: Just added it at the bottom. There's not much in the way of CSS here, but what's there might be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so that we could see it in action.

Comment: I looked and looked and see no class "pro-feature" on an element in the markup you posted, am I missing something?  I don't normally look at sites...for free.

Comment: Just set up a fiddle and am adding it here. Thanks for the advice @davehale23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you are having a `z-index` issue here.  I believe that you are having a problem propagating an event through a disabled element.  FF and Chrome apparently will propagate a `click` event up the chain to the next element, however IE will not.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input) deals with a similar problem, but with FF.  Their solutions also fail in IE, but it's worth looking over that post to see more details.

[Here is a solution](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2010/4/23/Attaching-mouse-events-to-a-disabled-input-element) that works in Chrome and IE at least.  And here is your fiddle [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/dfkBb/10/) to use this solution.

The code is very similar to that of the solution above, I only changed the "parent" element in line 17 and the actual click function in line 39.  I also removed the original click handler.  I added another radio button to the fiddle so that you could see that my solution should not interfere with existing "non-disabled" elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also found a solution. Turns out an element in I.E. requires a background-color in order to attach a click event to it.

Comment: Now that I look at it, is seems we got our answer from the same source. ;) Thanks for your help!