# How to disable/enable a checkbox on right-click in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-click

I wrote some code which allows me to disable/enable checkboxes when I right-click them. It works in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox.

```
rightClickFunc: function (e) 
{
    var obj;
    if ($.browser.msie) obj = event.srcElement;
    else obj = e.target;
    stuff.disableEnableObject(obj);
    return false;
},

disableEnableObject: function (o)
{
    if (o.getAttribute("disabled") == null)                
          $('#'+o.id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    else  $('#'+o.id).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

How can I get the same functionality in Chrome as IE?
The problem seems to be that right clicking on a disabled item in chrome does open the context menu (right click menu).

I made a sample of the code - see http://jsfiddle.net/e72M6/. Run it in IE and chrome to see the difference.  (IE can enable the boxes, Chrome cannot).

I want the other browser to have the same functionally as IE. So the boxes can be enabled.

Comment: It would be a lot of work, but technically when you disable the element, you could stack a transparent element on top of it (so the user can't see it), same size/shape, and listen for that `click` event. When it's enabled, hide/remove that stacked element

Comment: +1 for good-formulated question with fiddle and initial research!

Comment: @Ian I think you mean "transparent element"?

Comment: Also note that this code disables context menus on every item on the page.

Comment: You don't need to normalize `e`, jQuery does it for you. Just use `e.target` and it will be cross-browser consistent with getting the right element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e72M6/6/  it works with input type input :P i was really hoping there would be a trick to tell chrome that its ok to right click on disabled stuff even if its css or something wierd

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3100319/2170192

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a lot of work, but technically when you disable the element, you could stack a transparent element on top of it (so the user can't see it), same size/shape, and listen for that click event. When it's enabled, hide that stacked element.

Here's something to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/8dYXd/2/

It uses this structure:

```
<span>
    <input id='a' type='checkbox' disabled="disabled" />
    <span class="disabled-detector"></span>
</span>
```

And this CSS:

```
span {
    position: relative;
}

span.disabled-detector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

input+span.disabled-detector {
    display: none;
}

input[disabled]+span.disabled-detector {
    display: inline;
}
```

Notice how you can still "click" on disabled elements.

You'll have to update it to make sure the `click` (or `contextmenu`) event targets both the `input` and the transparent element. Technically, you could just use the parent `<span>` - give it a special class, and listen for `click` events on that. The events will bubble up from its descendants, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

According to the spec disabled elements should not respond to click events.

What you want to do is overlay an invisible (`opacity: 0`) element on top of this and use it as a proxy for your events. Just bear in mind that some old browsers don't understand `opacity`.

Comment: When you say "According to spec" what spec are you referring to?

Comment: [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled): `disabled` _When set for a form control, this boolean attribute disables the control for user input_

Answer (score 2):

It works to disable the element, but not to re-enable it.  This is because disabled elements do not fire mouse events.  I do not think that there is a way for you to get this to work in all browsers.