# Add onclick to disabled input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, inputbox

I have a table in which there are checkboxes, some checkboxes are disabled. I want to add an `onclick` attribute to all disabled checkboxes using JavaScript or jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<table class="docs_table" id="myTable2">
<tr id="node-22" class="disabled_element">
<td title="Document can't be selected.">
    <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname" value="/root/docname" disabled />
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-23" class="">
<td title="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname2" value="/root/docname2" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="node-24" class="disabled_element">
<td title="Document can't be selected.">    
    <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname3" value="/root/docname3" disabled />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In above code the `docname` input box should get below as onclick.

`onclick="javascript:if(confirm('Press OK to confirm')){ document.location='/pathtoscript?command=dosomething&amp;name=docname'};return false;"`

and `docname3` should get the below

`onclick="javascript:if(confirm('Press OK to confirm')){ document.location='/pathtoscript?command=dosomething&amp;name=docname3'};return false;"`

**What I tried**

```
 $('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($( this ).prop('disabled')) {
        $( this ).closest('tr').addClass('lineThrough');
        $( this ).attr('onClick','onclick="javascript:if(confirm('Press OK to confirm')){ document.location='/pathtoscript?command=dosomething&amp;name=docname'};return false;"');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, and also I wonder how to deal with different docname because in onclick statement `name=docname` will be different for each input box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnwwg/)

Comment: Disabled inputs don't register many/all events

Comment: Then onclick may be added to closest `<td>` or `<tr>`.

Comment: And of course your code won't work - you're not properly quoting the attribute value. You shouldn't be setting the `onclick` attribute with jQuery when you can correctly bind events with `.on()`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak We can add it to closest td but that wouldn't give the same feel as clicking on the checkbox right? Anyways, you can have a look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9k8kp/) for the closest <td> click. Remember to click just outside the checkbox.

Comment: @Harry That defeats the purpose of clicking on the checkbox...

Comment: @Ian: Yes mate, I have mentioned that in my comment too, but just showed a sample on how to do the closest td click.

Comment: @Harry: Your solution adds `onclick` to disabled checkboxes, but it doesn't change `name=docname` to `name=docname3` for 3rd checkbox.

Comment: @Ian one can enable it later and it will work!!!

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: I did it just to show a sample of the click event mate. If you want to proceed with this way, I will modify the code for you. But I suggest you to have a look at Pietu1998's answer first.

Comment: @Harry: OK. Yes, I see that. I would like to see your complete answer. Although Pietu's answer is the best way but I can't add extra divs in HTML, see my comment on his answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: Please check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9k8kp/). If you are Ok with it, I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Harry: Thanks, do add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, it is not possible for you to change your existing HTML structure and want to perform the action on click of the closest `<td>` element, please use the below code.

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if ($( this ).prop('disabled')) {
        $( this ).closest('tr').addClass('lineThrough');
        var valStr = $(this).val();
        $( this ).closest('td').attr('onClick', 'clickFn("'+valStr+'");');
        //console.log($( this ).closest('td').attr('onClick'));
    }});
});

function clickFn(valStr){ 
    if(confirm('Press OK to confirm')){ 
        valStr = valStr.substring(valStr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        newHref = '/pathtoscript?command=dosomething&amp;name=' +valStr;
        //console.log(newHref);
        document.location = newHref;
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9k8kp/)

Answer (score 4):

I did it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input).

```
<table class="docs_table" id="myTable2">
    <tr id="node-22" class="disabled_element">
        <td title="Document is being edited by someone.">
            <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname" value="/root/docname" disabled />
                <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="node-23" class="child">
        <td title="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname2" value="/root/docname2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="node-22" class="disabled_element">
        <td title="Document is being edited by someone.">
            <div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="docs" id="/root/docname3" value="/root/docname3" disabled />
                <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

```
 $('table tr td input[type="checkbox"] + div').each(function () {
     if ($(this).prev('input[disabled]')) {
         $(this).closest('tr').addClass('lineThrough');
         $(this).click(function () {
             if (confirm('Press OK to confirm')) {
                 var docname = $(this).prev('input[disabled]').prop('value');
                 docname = docname.substring(docname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                 document.location = '/pathtoscript?command=dosomething&amp;name=' + docname;
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Disabled elements don't generate mouse events. So basically what I did is added a `div` around the disabled `input`s and added some JS to match it.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnwwg/4/)**

Comment: This is the only real way to deal with mouse events on disabled inputs

Comment: Thanks, but I want `name=docname` on `onclick` to be different for 1st and 3rd checkbox. For 1st it will be `name=docname` but for 3rd it will be `name=docname3`.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak OK, modified code to do that based on the string in the `value` attribute after the last `/` in it.

Comment: Thanks @Pietu1998. But I can't modify my HTML to add `div`. So can this `div` be added to disabled checkboxes using jQuery only?

Comment: Trying to do that but I have to go to school. It is giving me `TypeError: this._containers is undefined`. If somebody wants they can fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnwwg/5/

Comment: OK. You're using your HTML, you should use mine (from question), where there's no div and try to add div from jQuery. I'm not in hurry, you can have a look at it in evening, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I'm somewhat successful to add `div` using jQuery but the first `div` is automatically adding ending `</div>` tag which should not happen. http://jsfiddle.net/Xnwwg/6/