# Disabled elements, ondblclick with <span>

Tags: html, onclick, disabled-input, javascript

I have several different elements on my page, and some of them are disabled. I want I way to be able to still use the ondblclick, and onclick events when the elements are disabled. I asked a previous question on this, and the answer that I received was to wrap the element in a `<span>`, which had a double click, therefore allowing the dblclick event to fire.

However, this does not work for all the elements on the page. I have `<textarea>`, `<button>`, `<input type="text">`, `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">`. The `<span>` workaround does not work for all of these.

Why not? What can I do to make all of the elements ondblclick work even when they are disabled?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eG7xE/1/)

Comment: You cannot. Disabled elements are impervious to mouse events. Even if you wrap them with `<span>` elements, the events won't bubble up to them because they won't be handled in the first place. Consider using `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: That's kind of the point of disabled elements. They are disabled.

Comment: A similar question with a possible workaround was posted at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Can you tell me why using a span works with some elements, but not with others?

Comment: Probably because the other elements you speak of are not form controls, and as such cannot be disabled in the first place.