# Clicking on a disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable a radio button but to be able to get the on-click event when it is disabled. Then I enclose the radio button in a div:

```
<div id="div_radio" display="block"><input type="radio" id="radio"/></div>
```

and I do, for example:

```
$("#div_radio").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/stla/6CKwk/2/

It works but one has to click not exactly on the radio button, and that is my problem. I have found several related questions on SO, but as a newbie in html/javascript it is possible that I have misunderstood some solutions.

Comment: What's that `display="block"` attribute?

Comment: Just looking at the fiddle and not your markup, since there's a single input, why are you using a radio button for this and not a checkbox, or even a button?

Comment: @MaxArt I don't know, but that doesn't change anything to remove it.

Comment: @StuperUser This is just a simplified example of my real situation...

Comment: you can find your answer from this post [event-on-a-disabled-input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/3129183)

Comment: Try setting the selector to the label instead of the div for the `hide()` method. So `$(".radio")` . it's not perfect but the nature of labels results in a much more generous clickable area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pointer-events` CSS property on modern browsers:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CKwk/4/)

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#radio").prop('disabled',true).css('pointer-events','none');
});
```

Comment: Guess I didn't understand the question at all. I thought OP _only_ wanted the click event on the radio itself.

Comment: @andyb indeed, OP wants click on disabled radio button to still propagate to its parent DIV

Comment: Yes @andyb and this is not directly possible when the radio is disabled. Compare my jsfiddle to the one of A. Wolff.

Comment: Yes thanks I understand the problem now. _I think_ this is the only way to do it. Even a `z-index`'d overlay won't work as the browser itself it stopping the mouse events on disabled controls. You can't even _right click_ on disabled elements in Chrome

Comment: @andyb for full browser support, the way would be to put an element in front of the radio button when disabled. This is another possibility.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your real situation?

Comment: @A.Wolff I'd like but is not easy... This is a shiny app actually. When the button is disabled then the click doesn't work at all (even when clicking not exactly on the button)

Comment: @A.Wolff It works with `(".radio")` instead of `("#div_radio")`, but I have other radio buttons then I need to do more work

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent not sure what you are talking about but IDs must be unique on document context. If a class selector works but not the id one for the same element, then obviously you have duplicated IDs

Comment: @A.Wolff There's no duplicated id. It works by doing `<label class="radio arbitrary_name"><input type="radio"...` and then by getting the event on the class `arbitrary_name`. Sorry for not being able to show you the real situation.