# Mouseover Mouseout not work in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

i have textbox inside div .cshtml view page

```
@if(Model.WorkFlowValue=="Qualified" || Model.WorkFlowValue=="Not Qualified")
{
<div id="textboxWorkFlow">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkFlowValue, new { @class = "col8 last right status-field", disabled = "disabled" })
</div>
}
else
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkFlowValue, new { @class = "col8 last right status-field", disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

in javascript mouseover event fire successfully in google Chrome but fail in FireFox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#textboxWorkFlow").mouseover(function(){
console.log('Mouse In');
}).mouseout(function(){
console.log('Mouse Out');
});
});
```

Rendered controls in Browser

```
<div id="textboxWorkFlow"> <input id="WorkFlowValue" class="col8 last right status-field" type="text" value="Qualified" name="WorkFlowValue" disabled="disabled"> </div>
```

Fiddle please test in Firefox.
http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/143/

Comment: use mouseenter instead of mouseover and use mouseleave instead of mouseout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the solution firefox encountered a bug http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11382

disable property is not working with firefox just use readonly property instead of disable.

```
@if(Model.WorkFlowValue=="Qualified" || Model.WorkFlowValue=="Not Qualified")
{
<div id="textboxWorkFlow">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkFlowValue, new { @class = "col8 last right status-field", @readonly = "true" }) //replace disabled with readonly
</div>
}
else
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkFlowValue, new { @class = "col8 last right status-field", @readonly = "true" })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try to use mouseenter instead of mouseover and mouseleave instead of mouse out

```
$("#textboxWorkFlow").mouseenter(function() {

});

$("#textboxWorkFlow").mouseleave(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#textboxWorkFlow").on("mouseenter",function(){
       alert('mouse In');
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
       alert('Mouse Out');
    });
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/110/)

**EDIT**
As per our discussion, it is found that mouse event does not work for disabled inputs.
[See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

There is a work around like below. need to use div with absolute position.

```
<div id="textboxWorkFlow" style="position:relative;">
<input type="text" id="workflow" disabled="disabled"/>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Working [JSFiddle for Disabled Input](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/153/)

Comment: I have tried this on firefox and it is working form me. any console errors on browser ... can you share this in jsfiddle

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge, i think there is problem with expression inside div, can you pls try same by replace some static text inside div and remove existing. like <div id="textboxWorkFlow" >Some Text here</div>

Comment: it is working when i try static text as you say but in my scenario i have to render Textbox dynamically after checking the condition like that... i update my question please check

Comment: ok can you try with .on for mouse event binding as updated in answer

Comment: yes i try @bhushan but not work ... :( still working fine in Chrome

Comment: Can you please suggest me any other option...??

Comment: I think there is no issue in jQuery script as it is working on chrome. there might be some browser specific issue.. please follow this link and try to find out error on browser console https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Error_Console

Comment: when i try without disabling my textfield it is working fine with Firefox also but in my case i want to disable this field but want to show tooltip on hover.. Have you any idea how to do...??

Comment: try using disabled = "true" instead of disabled = "disabled".

Comment: it is updated Fiddle please Check in Firefox... <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/143/">Fiddle</a>

Comment: @Bhusshan i try with disabled="true" but not working

Answer (score 0):

created this fiddle to replicate your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#textboxWorkFlow").mouseover(function(){
alert('Mouse In');
}).mouseout(function(){
alert('Mouse Out');
});
});
```

this works for me in all browsers  http://jsfiddle.net/65ak7/

please check if there are not two elements on the page with same id.

Comment: I did the same way you suggest actually i am showing a tooltip when user move mouse on it and hide this tooltip when he swap out from the textbox... When i insert break point in my javascript code then this event fire without hovering of mouse at the time of loading.

Comment: can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle. or else try mouseenter, here's a link that explains it http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: strange it works for me in firefox too, the tooltip shows up when i hover over the div

Comment: can you check once if there are multiple controls being rendered for "WorkFlowValue" textbox or "textboxWorkFlow" div, check in the view source, otherwise i dont see a problem with the jquery codes.

Comment: Rendering Control
<div id="textboxWorkFlow">
<input id="WorkFlowValue" class="col8 last right status-field" type="text" value="Qualified" name="WorkFlowValue" disabled="disabled">
</div>

Comment: when i try without disabling my textfield it is working fine with Firefox also but in my case i want to disable this field but want to show tooltip on hover.. Have you any idea how to do...??

Comment: i came out with a fix.. use this in your div style="display:block;padding:1px;" and it will work in firefox also

Comment: please check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/143/ as you say i do but it effect by custom css and not working properly as it is fire on some special area of textbox not with the area of whole textbox.... Can you please take look and suggest