# Make alert window when clicking a disabled button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, checkbox

I have a button which by default is disable, but when a checkbox is checked the button is then enabled. I would like to edit the script to make an alert window when the button is clicked when disabled, to make sure the user knows he/she has to check the checkbox.

My script so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#terms').on('change', function(){
          if ($(this).is(':checked')){
             $('#customButton').removeProp('disabled');
          }
          else{
             $('#customButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
       });
</script>

<form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
<input type="image"  src="button3.png" id="customButton" value="submit" alt="button" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You want to trigger event handler on the click of `disabled` button?

Comment: I want to trigger a function which, if the button is disabled and clicked an alert window pops up.

Comment: You are missing the point, `disabled` element do not trigger events. Test it yourself http://jsfiddle.net/ym34ud8j/

Comment: you should check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/9oxdnw40/)

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" />
<input type="button"  id="customButton" value="submit" alt="button" class="disabled"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#terms').on('change', function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#customButton').removeClass('disabled');
}
else{
    $('#customButton').addClass('disabled');
}
});

$('#customButton').on('click',function(e){
if( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please confirm . . .');
}else{
    alert('go ahead...');
};
});
```

The long and short of it is, if an element is 'disabled' all events that happen on it are suppressed. In my fiddle I've 'faked' a disabled button using a style so the click event is still visible to the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited it abit, but it got me on the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#customButton").click(function(){
if !($("#terms").is(':checked'))
 {
 alert("Accept terms first!");
 }
})
```

if your browser can not detect click on a disabled button, Warp the button inside a div and change the function to click on that div.

Comment: This helped me. I didn't think of wrapping my disabled button inside a div in order to capture the click event.