# Div click event when div is inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, click

I have troubles to show an alert when a button (actually an input type=image object) is disabled because user should first to click on a terms checkbox. 
This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#divButton').on("click", function() {
    if ($('#buybutton').prop('disabled', true)) {
        alert('Please confirm . . .');
    }
});
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
    <form>
      ...
        <div id="divButton">
            <input type="image" id="buybutton"...

        </div>
    </form>
```

When `buybutton` is disabled and I click inside `divButton` (over disabled button for example) nothing happens.

I am a mobile developer trying to write JavaScript code, so be patient with me.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Debugging it on Chrome, when `buybutton` is disabled it is never entering inside divButton's click handler  function to check

```
if ($('#buybutton').prop('disabled', true)).
```

Looks like onClick event in that div be disabled.

Comment: `if($('#buybutton').prop('disabled', true))` that is saying set disabled to true and it make sure the jQuery object is truthy.... It is not checking to see if it is disabled

Comment: Also not sure how you are clicking on a disabled button..... The event does not bubble up from the button.

Comment: Would you be better off using `<input type="button" class="buyButton"  onclick="buyEvent()"/>` where `.buyButton` in the `CSS` sets the background of the button to whatever "buy" image you want. From there, you can just create a `function buyEvent() { }` and do whatever logic you want?

Comment: Why wrap the image button in a div in the first place? Clicking a disabled button doesn't trigger a click event, so it looks like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nrc809Ly/

Comment: @EGC `input type="image"` was created for precisely the use case the OP is using it for; namely, an image with button semantics. You can add `onclick="buyEvent()"` to an `input type="image"` and it will work the same as adding the same to an `input type="button"`.

Comment: It seems like what you want is a disabled button, but to allow the user to click on it, and then show a warning before the "disabled" part kicks in. If that's the case, just leave the button enabled, but set some other property (say, `.attr('data-disabled', true)` or `data-disabled="true"` in HTML) and check that value in your click event handler. If it's true, show your warning and return. If it's false, do whatever your button is supposed to do when enabled.

Answer (score 0):

best approach is Pat Dobson's recipe, is not exactly the same than I was trying to do, but can works:

[Make alert window when clicking a disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913997/make-alert-window-when-clicking-a-disabled-button)

Thanks for your help, guys ;-)