# How to prevent a select from showing drop-down temporarily?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, user-experience

I have a page where I have many `select`s that show tons of options (think of something like 75 `select`s with 200 hundred options each). I realize that this is ugly/bad idea/etc. To make things a bit more snappy, I only include one `option` by default in each select and then on the `click` event, I add the rest. This works fine, but there is a split-second when the `select` shows its drop-down that only has one `option` and then shows the rest a split-second later.

Is there a way to "pause" the drop-down from showing itself until after I have added the other 'option's?

Here is the code if that helps:

```
$(document).on('click', 'select', function(){
  var thisJQ = $(this);
  if (thisJQ.children().length > 1) {
    return;
  }

  var values = otherOptions ; // defined elsewhere

  var optSelected = thisJQ.children('option:selected');
  var opts = [];
  values.forEach(function(obj, index){
    if (parseInt(optSelected.val(), 10) === obj["id"]) {
      return;
    }

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj["desc"]));
    opt.setAttribute('value', obj["id"]);
    opts.push(opt);
  })
  thisJQ.append(opts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only way to prevent the `select` from dropping down is to disable it, but in my case that would be a problem because a disabled input cannot receive a `click event`. So, I ended up following the solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/99971) (although there are some other answers posted to this question that are interesting as well). It adds two more `div`s to each `select` and it requires one more click but the effect is clean.