# how to capture doubleclick on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to perform action in javascript on detecting double click. Can you please let me know the same? This is a complex control combining label+ checkbox.

```
<td class=" odd" title="Double click to edit.">
<label class="cb_label_right">
<input id="check1_table#rowName#0" type="checkbox" data-ctrl="JSCtrl" disabled="">
<span>Row Name</span>
</label>

tablecell.ondblclick = function(){alert( "Double Clicked" );};
```

In the above line, if I click on label; double click is detected but not on checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
<span>Fat Lock11</span>
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;">
</div>
```

The above code is working for sample code. I am new to Javascript, how to convert to Javascript as a single line

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Are you listening `checked`/`unchecked` events ?

Comment: Ask yourself when is the last time you doubleclicked a checkbox? It's not something you ever see, and doesn't seem very intuitive. Also note that *you can not click a disabled input*, mouse events aren't fired.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( "#check1").dblclick(function() {
  alert( "Double Clicked" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" data-ctrl="JSCtrl">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#check1').on('dblclick',function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" data-ctrl="JSCtrl">
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$( "#check1").bind("dblclick",function() {
   console.log("event occur");
});
```

Comment: How is this any different from what ViKu's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36694600/369450) already said to do?

Comment: The above solutions are not working for my complex control. Any other suggestions please

Comment: can you please share fiddle ?

Comment: I edited my query where adding div is helping my problem. But unfortunately it is working for one row only. If multiple rows are present then focus is shifting to last row and action corresponding to double click is performed on this last row.