# Why doesn't uib-tooltip on a div wrapping a disabled input work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I used an angular ui-bootstrap tooltip on a div that wrapped an input so that the tooltip could display if the button was disabled.  In ui-bootstrap 0.14.3 this worked, but ui-bootstrap version 1.3.2 behaves differently.  The tooltip doesn't pop up with Chrome.  (But, it works in Firefox.)

Try changing the ui-bootstrap version as mentioned in the comments in the code here to see the difference between behavior with different versions: http://plnkr.co/edit/yhyNzcniT4YoqAoNbXQC?p=preview

I could do this css workaround:

```
.btn[disabled] {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

But that would affect the `cursor: not-allowed` symbol, and I worry about other implications.

How come uib-tooltip on a div wrapping a disabled input doesn't work anymore? Is #4322 (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4322) related?

What's a good way to get this to work (without jquery)?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5012, which points to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input. Basically, you can't.