# jQueryUI draggable fails at least with <input> element

Tags: jquery-ui

I have problems to set elements draggable using jQueryUI 1.12.1.
There is no problem, when draggable element is `<div>`, but when I switched it to the `<input ... >`, it does not move from place. I tried to disable  element too in order to make it more "stiff", but it makes no difference. 
The similarly pitiful outcomes I had with resizing `<label>` for `<input>`. I could move it on the screen, but I was unable to resize it.

Here is code I just copied from the page and made minor changes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>resizable demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #brick {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}   </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <label id="brickLabel" for="brick">Brick is stiff</label>
    <input type='text' id="brick" disabled/>
    <div id="goodBrick" style="width: 100px; height: 70px; background-color: #EF45fE"></div>

<script>
$( "#goodBrick" ).draggable();
$( "#goodBrick" ).resizable();    
$( "#brick" ).draggable();
$( "#brick" ).resizable();
$( "#brickLabel" ).draggable();
$( "#brickLabel" ).resizable();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So where I do mistake?

Comment: Click events do not fire on disabled elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: Outside of using a handle or `.stopPropagation()` to unbind the click event that is part of the element, you could work around it some: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e59novst/4/