# Firefox not registering click event on surrounding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, input

I have the following code:

```
<div data-type="nameHolder">
   <input data-type="name" disabled="">
</div>
```

My idea is to keep the input disabled and only when you double click on it to enable it. However since click events are not detected on disabled elements I'm using a holder div. This works fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please add your jQuery code too

Comment: Give Ur tried code in fiddle, may that will help to recode for firfox.

Comment: why not just make it read-only instead?

Comment: You can use `event delegation` instead. I hope that will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since disabled elements don't fire events, you can use a div as a wrapper over your input and attach event handler to this div. when you double click on wrapper div, enable the input and hide the wrapper div.

```js
$('.wrapper').dblclick(function(){
 $(this).prev('input').attr('disabled', false);
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-type="nameHolder">
   <input data-type="name" disabled="">
   <div class="wrapper" style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a solution for your case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input). Author proposed to place an element in front of the disabled input and catch the click on that element for crossbrowser support.