# Angularjs: Handle click on disabled radio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, radio-button

I would like to handle clicks on disabled radio button and its label using Angularjs.

```
//html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <label data-ng-click="handleClick()">
      <input type="radio" value="1" data-ng-disabled="true">
      Value 1
    </label>
    <label data-ng-click="handleClick()">
      <input type="radio" value="2" >
      Value 2
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

//javascipt
function TempCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.handleClick = function() {
    alert('handleClick')
  };

}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn689tod/2/). So when user clicks on disabled radio, alert should appear. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly you need? Can you please elaborate more.. It looks interesting..

Comment: @PankajParkar When user clicks on disabled radio button and input, notice should be displayed. When user clicks on not disabled radio, some calculations are performed. All the logic in the handleClick function. I simple left alert to simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

See the below snippet for answer

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <label for="input1" data-ng-click="handleClick('input1')">
      <input name="input1" id="input1" type="radio" value="1" data-ng-disabled="true">
      Value 1
    </label>
    <label for="input2" data-ng-click="handleClick('input2')">
      <input name="input2" id="input2" type="radio" value="2" >
      Value 2
    </label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $("#input1").prop('disabled',true).css('pointer-events','none');
$scope.handleClick = function(id) {
    var disabled=$("#"+id).attr('disabled');
    if(disabled=='disabled'){
    alert("disabled")
    }
  };
}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still can't see alert when click on disabled input

Comment: just try the click on label

Comment: In my jsfiddle alert is displayed when i click on labels. The idea is to display alert when user clicks on disabled radio button.

Comment: i couldn't see any alert on your jsfiddle

Comment: My fault, there was a console.log. I updated original post with link to alert version.

Comment: you can not click a disable input

Comment: just add  $("#input1").prop('disabled',true).css('pointer-events','none');

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it didn't work. Now that it seems to be working, I cannot upvote it (unless you edit your answer). Please, add an explaination to your code and I'll change my vote.

Comment: changed the answer

Answer (score 1):

According to this:
[Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

you are not able.

One approach would be to not to disable it, and set up a class:

```
 [class.notReallyDisabled]="w/e"
```

And then use CSS to change its aspect.

Comment: In this case value will be set on input and I will need to revert it. I'm interested in more elegant solution actually. But if I dont' find anything, I'll have to go this way.