# ng-click not working on child input tag (mozilla firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mozilla

```
<div ng-click="hello()">
    <input type="password" disabled>
</div>
```

i have got the above HTML script .

parent div has a click function . when i click on child input tag in firefox the click event of parent is not working however in chrome it is working fine . removing disabled from input tag will make it work fine on mozilla , however i require this input tag to be disabled.

how to make it work on firefox without eliminating disabled from input tag

Comment: Shouldn't ng-click be onclick? Or are you using angularjs?

Comment: no 
i m using angular 1 js

Comment: Please show the parent click and the controllers

Comment: <div ng-click="hello()"> - this is parent div .  . . . . . .
<input type="password" disabled> -  this is child div

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but since I just lost the better part of an hour on the same issue while working on my angular 8 project, I thought I'd anyway post the answer that worked for me.

First off, this is not really an Angular issue, but a Firefox issue. It seems that Firefox simply does not fire click events from disabled input fields. Therefore, when clicking the input, there is no event to propagate to the parent. Checkout this thread for more information: [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input). Incidentally, I found this solution in a comment on the accepted answer, so credit goes to [Doin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999120/doin).

So the easiest way around this behavior is by adding the following css style to the input element:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This prevents the element from reacting to pointer events, which means that the pointer event is also not "absorbed" by the disabled input and fires from the parent element.

See below for a complete example:

```js
function hello() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hi there!';
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div input:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="hello()">
    <input type="password" disabled>
</div>

<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It really helped me with the same issue.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Had the same issue. Took me a lot longer since I didn't want to check out this thread for a while because the title was angular related and I thought it was a React issue.

Comment: Worth to mention it also works for Vue.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with **readonly** instead of **disabled**?

```
<div ng-click="hello()">
<input type="password" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i have 
. . but as i mentioned my requirement for app doesn't allow me to remove "disabled"