# How to make the one value disable in @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

Hi this is my code for Check box. I want to

```
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AccountUser.AdminAccess, new
                                       {
                                           data_on_text = "YES",
                                           data_off_text = "NO",
                                           data_on_color = "success",
                                           data_off_color = "danger",
                                           @class = "switchCheckbox",
                                           disabled = "disabled"
                                       })
```

If I use  disabled = "disabled" attr. then it is going to disable whole Check box. I want to disable the No value of Check box. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick event to toggle values of checkbox. But you can disable input only [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

```
 $('#checkbox').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {          
    } else {
        $(this).attr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is some example code to show you how I would solve this:

```
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.AdminAccess, new
            {
                data_on_text = "YES",
                data_off_text = "NO",
                data_on_color = "success",
                data_off_color = "danger",
                @class = "switchCheckbox",
            })  

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    if (!$("#AdminAccess").prop("checked"))
                        $("#AdminAccess").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
                });

            </script>
```