# JS display div on click of disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the `.hideme` message on click of `submit` only when it is **disabled**.

And the `.hideme` should be unique for each `submit`. I'm not sure if I should use data-attributes to associate them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post-1").hide();
  $("#post-1").click(postNotification);
});

function postNotification() {
  $("#post-1")
    .show()
    .animate({
      height: "30px",
      opacity: 1
    }, 250)
    .delay(2000)
    .animate({
      height: "0px",
      opacity: 0
    }, 250);
}
```

```css
.hideme {
  background: blue;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <div class="hideme" id="post1">Message 1</div>
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/>
  <input type="submit" data-submit="1" id="post1" disabled></input>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <div class="hideme" id="post2">Message 2</div>
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/>
  <input type="submit" data-submit="2" id="post2"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicated id's .. and on html you're using `post1` and on js you're using `post-1`

Comment: Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. 
 You'll have to try a different solution. 
 Possibly creating `divs` that "look" like buttons, and changing the classes of `pointer:cursor;` etc etc
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using (disabled) you can use css to make element seem to be disabled

```
.disabled
{
color:#C0C0C0;
}
```

then add this class to input instead of disabled

```
<input type="submit" data-submit="1" class="btn disabled" id="post1" ></input>
```

and in jquery detect that element has enabled or disabled class and decide which action should be done

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn").click(
function(event){
if($(event.target).hasClass("disabled")){
event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".hideme").style.opacity="1";
event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".hideme").style.height="30";
}else{
alert("action");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't click on disabled tags.
You can use a class "disabled":

```
<style>
    .hideme {
      background: blue;
      height: 0px;
      opacity: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .disabled{
        color: #000;
        opacity: .65;
    }
</style>
```

Use the same class to show onclick

```
    <div class="first">
      <div class="hideme ">Message 1</div>
      <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/>
      <input type="submit" data-submit="1" id="post1" class="disabled" ></input>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div class="hideme ">Message 2</div>
      <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required/>
      <input type="submit" data-submit="2" id="post2" class="disabled"></input>
    </div>
```

Use siblings to get the class ".hideme". Now every disabled button will show the message:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".msg").hide();

        $(".disabled").click(function(){
            var id = "#"+ this.id;
            $(id).siblings(".hideme")
                .show()
                .animate({
                  height: "30px",
                  opacity: 1
                }, 250)
                .delay(2000)
                .animate({
                  height: "0px",
                  opacity: 0
                }, 250);

        });
    });
</script>
```