# How to use click() on disabled element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox element with id `#tmcp_choice_5_0_22`

And and have this code which works fine:

```
$('input#tmcp_choice_5_0_22').click(function(){
    alert('Does this work?');
});
```

Problems happens when the checkbox is 'disabled', it seems that the `click()` function doesn't work in disabled elements.

Is there other function I could use for this instead of `click()`?

The duplicated question doesn't help me, because I can not put another element in the HTML, the html code is generated by a wordpress plugin.

Comment: Try `.mousedown()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input)

Comment: Have you tried `mousedown` as Barmar suggested?

Comment: As a last resort, you could use jquery to insert the element into the HTML.

Comment: Another option: does the plugin expose any filters that allow you to change the HTML? Finally: Look again at some of the answers in the linked question. Not all of them require you to change the HTML.

Comment: `mousedown` will not work; disabled elements fire no mouse events at all.

Answer (score 2):

> IMHO the simplest, cleanest way to "fix" this (if you do in fact need
>   to capture clicks on disabled elements like the OP does) is just to
>   add the following CSS to your page:
>
> ```
> input[disabled] {pointer-events:none}
> ```
>
> This will make any clicks on a disabled input fall through to the
>   parent element, where you can capture them normally. (If you have
>   several disabled inputs, you might want to put each into an individual
>   container of its own, if they aren't already laid out that way - an
>   extra `<span>` or a `<div>`, say - just to make it easy to distinguish
>   which disabled input was clicked).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925830/2518200