# Angular 6 checkbox click event when disabled

Tags: angular, onclick

I want to call a method that shows a warning toaster when i click on my disabled checkbox.

So here is my code:

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"
    [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox" 
    [disabled]="!hasCar"
    (change)="noCarToastr()"/>
</label>
```

TypeScript code:

```js
noCarToastr(){
  let me  = this;
  if(!hasCar){
    me.toastr.warning("No Car Available");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing that issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not trigger javascript events on a disabled element. Add the click listener over the `label` element.

```
<label (click)="noCarToastr()">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"
        [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox" 
        [disabled]="!hasCar"
        (change)="noCarToastr(); $event.stopPropagation()"/>
        Car
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) elements won't fire mouse event, so instead of disabling just prevent the click action based on the `hasCar` property value which will prevent from checking the checkbox. For preventing the action use [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) reference and [`Event#preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method.

*Template :*

```
<label for="abc">test
    <input id="abc" type="checkbox" checked="checked"
        [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox" 
        (click)="noCarToastr($event, hasCar)"
        />
</label>
```

*Component :*

```
noCarToastr(event: Event) {
  let me = this;
  if (!this.hasCar) {
    event.preventDefault()
    me.toastr.warning("No Car Available");
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amoho5)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using @Output(change) use @Output(click), as change will only trigger when value of input is changed.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"
        [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox" 
        [disabled]="!hasCar"
        (click)="noCarToastr()"/>
</label>
```

I would recommend using angular material as it provide other more intuitive option.

Hope this helps,