# Get mouse coordinates when the mouse is over a disabled element?

Tags: javascript

When using a global `mousemove` event attached to the `window` object, the mouse coordinates are not available when the mouse moves over a *disabled* element. Disabled elements do not fire any events, presenting a problem.

Part of my application includes a free-transform tool which allows elements to be rotated, scaled, resized and dragged around the viewport (drag & drop). The flow of my app is broken if the mouse is moved over a disabled element while freely transforming an object, because suddenly the mouse coordinates are not available to my objects until the mouse leaves the element, giving a choppy / laggy feel and a poor user experience.

I've tried the `readonly` attribute instead. However, this is not a viable solution as it is only supported by two elements (input and textarea) source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 and has different behaviour.

Here's a Fiddle showing the choppy / laggy behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/rmw9anLs/2/

I understand the element itself doesn't fire any events, but I'm not attaching any events to the disabled element. I would expect the `window.mousemove` event to fire regardless and don't understand why a disabled element on the page would interrupt a global event listener.

Aside from implementing a custom `disabled` feature using JavaScript, is there a way to get the mouse coordinates without having to account for the mouse being on top of disabled elements?

Comment: `don't understand why a disabled element on the page would interrupt a global event listener` That is because of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). If the propagation is stopped anywhere during bubbling or capturing then it will not propagate any further (duh.)

Comment: have look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925830/7485705)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, hence the disabled attribute has no effect, other than making your HTML invalid.

To stop the mouse event working, attach an event handler to the element using `event.preventDefault()` on it, check for a `data-disabled` attribute on the element in your existing click handlers or use `pointer-events: none` in a CSS class which you toggle on/off as needed. Also be aware that pointer-events is not well supported in IE <11

E.g:
https://jsfiddle.net/x4nLu0a5/