# How to enabled/disable textarea in html on double clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am trying to enable textarea on double click but its not working:

```
<textarea name="manuf_comment[]" disabled ondblclick="this.disabled=false" ><?php echo $cases["manuf_comment"]; ?></textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong here? P.S: I want to do this in the element without calling JavaScript functions externally if possible.

Comment: The problem lies on the disabled textarea, it won't react on doubleclicks when once disabled.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, just disabled inputs(or textarea) do not fire mouse events, here's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input) for that

Comment: @VaheYavrumian what about backgroundcolor, can I change it doing this?

Comment: change backgroundColor by double click? I think you won't have any problem, but if there's anything, ask here, I'll help as much as I can

Comment: @VaheYavrumian thank you! I am doing it like this but it doesn't change the background color: `style="backgroundColor: lightgray;" onchange="this.readOnly='true'; this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='lightgray'" ondblclick="this.readOnly=''; this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='white'"` . I tried with `color` and it works by changing text color.

Comment: I tried to run this code in codepen, it works perfectly, just `onchange` event fires only when you click outside textarea

Comment: @VaheYavrumian fixed it! I removed the parentnode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217094/discussion-between-vahe-yavrumian-and-ttt).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an ondblclick event on disabled texarea's please put it intro a div and make the ondblclick event there.

```
<div ondblclick="enable(this)">
  <textarea name="manuf_comment[]" disabled ondblclick="hh(this)" >asdasd</textarea>
</div>​

<script>
function enable(div){
  div.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].disabled = false;
  console.log('sad');
}
</script>
```