# JQuery click event not triggering in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, events, click

i'm confused why jquery click event not working on firefox, but all other browsers working. Any idea?

```
$(".stockTreeItemHelperClick").bind("click", function(event) {

  $(this).parent().parent().children().each(function() {
    var tag = $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
    if(tag == "ul") {
      $(this).toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5gkuLc4/

Comment: It do work for me in firefox, but you have to click to the right of your input

Comment: You can try look her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated, you can use on function instead of bind