# How to show some text on click on disabled select

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on disabled select I get nothing. I need to do this without classes

```
 <select id="param" disabled></select>
```

```
$("#param").on("change click", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":disabled")) {
        console.log("disabled");
    } else {
        console.log("enabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: [Disabled elements do not fire event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/14956277).

Comment: In addition to previous comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled