# Click EventListener does not work if the child element is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

**Target**

I want the parent element to be clickable even though the child element is disabled.

**Example Code**

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('hello world')
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input disabled placeholder="foo">
</div>
```

**Important Note**

@Drag13 had pointed out to me that it works in `Chrome 96`. It does not work in `Firefox 95.0` on Linux OS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works in Chrome 96

Comment: @Drag13 Ok. I tested only in Firefox. Thank you for hint.

Comment: Works in my FF 95 (in snippet above).

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925830/17175441

Comment: @aerial301 The link is helpful. It shows some "hacks" to make it work in FF. It seems to be an old FF topic.But I didn't notice it until today. Merci!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Firefox problem and even an older one. In the Chrome browser, on the other hand, it works as expected. To get around the problem, you can use a little trick.

Add the CSS property: `pointer-events:none;` to the disbaled impunt field. This delegates the click to the parent element. The click is evaluated again in the parent element and should therefore work. Special thanks go to `@aerial301`.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('hello world, now it works :-)')
}, true);
```

```css
input[disabled] {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input disabled placeholder="foo">
</div>
```

Comment: Still wouldn't work tho if you have the input floating.